# solidify face same as extrude?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

I would like to add a thickness to a face, but solidify is making it same as extrude would. I need to pull surrounding faces as well.
Is there any way to do it? I have hi-poly scan so anything manual is out of question.

Here is the exact case: I need to add thick face to this loop
Thx!

[image]

EDIT: Best way so far.

Select edge loop - bevel -delete faces: 
you get two parallel loops
Select one loop - fill
Select second loop - fill

Comment: What you've got is called non-manifold geometry.

Comment: Yes, that's why Boolean don't work